# Task definition/definition in gradle

Tags: java, groovy, nullpointerexception, gradle

In a gradle build script when we declare a task as follows:

```
task lol

lol << {
    prinln "lol's action!"
}
```

and execute it as `gradle -q lol` it works fine. My question is why does `lol` task instance is already created and `NullPointerException` is not caused? Does declarartion `task lol` declare and define task simultaneously?

Comment: This isn't clear.  What would possibly throw an NPE here?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In Java JLS 4.12.5: _For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null._ That declaration doesn't contain any initializer, since I assume it was default-initalized with `null`.

Comment: Ok, but Gradle isn't Java.  It's a DSL built on top of Groovy.  The JLS won't help you interpret it.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth How could I acquire enough details to understand what default value of a variable is?

Comment: To understand this behavior you need to peek into the [Build Life Cycle in Gradle.](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) Understanding the build phases will make things clear.

Comment: @dmahapatro: I'm not sure what this has to do with the build life cycle?

Comment: @dmahapatro Does the instance of the task created by _lifeCycleManager_, if I could say so?

Comment: You're not actually creating a variable.  You're effectively calling `Project.task("lol")`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried to create task by calling `Project.task("hello")` in the build script. But the following exception was thrown _No signature of method: static org.gradle.api.Project.task() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hello]_

Comment: You're already in the scope of a `Project` object.  So you actually only need to write `task("lol")`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It also doesn't work. _No signature of method: build_1thp6kno4q1h1c6d8p39heiear$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGr
phExecuter) values: [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter@1a
f670]_

Comment: `task("lol")` should work just fine.  At any rate, I'm not really sure what problem you're trying to solve via this question.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth To understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

task is actually a method on [Project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) and `task lol` is invoking that method taking advantage of the [optional parens](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-optional-parenthesis.html). There is some groovy magic involved to turn `lol` into a String. The lol [Task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html) property on the Project then has the leftShift method invoked using the `<<` operator. See [operator overloading](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading).